# Increase the date from database by adding more days and display it in a table laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I create a table with display details from the database. The date from the database is displaying but I want to increase this displaying date by adding 3 days it will give me an effective date.

```
foreach ($data as $key => $priceBookDetail) {
                $dd = array();
                array_push($dd, $i);

                array_push($dd, $priceBookDetail->priceBook->name);             
                array_push($dd, $priceBookDetail->product->category->category_name);
                array_push($dd, $priceBookDetail->product->short_code);
                array_push($dd, $priceBookDetail->product->product_name);
                array_push($dd, $priceBookDetail->effective_date);
                array_push($dd, $priceBookDetail->price);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add Carbon to your project
[Nice tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/easier-datetime-in-laravel-and-php-with-carbon)

Then you'll be able to do

```
$yourdate->addDays(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simple and clean way is to use strtotime()

```
$date = strtotime("+3 day", strtotime($priceBookDetail->effective_date));
echo date("Y-m-d", $date);
```

Hope this code is helpful

Comment: Welcome @Shoba. Please accept the answer if other person facing same problem get help for this

Answer (score 0):

Try `date_add()`

Ripped shamelessly from the PHP docs:

```
$effectiveDate = date_create($priceBookDetail->dateField);
date_add($effectiveDate, date_interval_create_from_date_string('3 days'));
```

Then format date as you need

```
date_format($effectiveDate, 'Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 0):

while you are using laravel there is a pre install package name carbon who deals with date and time
just set use Carbon\Carbon; then feel free to use it

```
$dt = Carbon::create(2012, 1, 31, 0);

echo $dt->addDays(3);                       // 2012-02-03 00:00:00
```

for further assistance go this url http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Comment: always happy to help